# Firebase, Swift: Fetch snapshot based on specific value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase dataset:

- users

  - QZqFzWxpdMfc0xmyIq5IDAr1bzr2

    - credentials

      - email:  "myemail@gmail.com"
      - username:  "MyUsername"
  - RJasdfasfasdad3dadaewdsdkdq3dk

    - credentials

      - email:  "another@gmail.com"
      - username:  ""Another

and a snapshot query:

```
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```

How can I do a query so that only the ID for user with username "MyUsername" is returned?

E.g. can I do something like:

```
let query = "/*/credentials/[username=MyUsername]"
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(query)
```

Comment: What is `RJasdfasfasdad3dadaewdsdkdq3dk `, userId?

Comment: It is a array, just loop and get all the usernames

Comment: @ĐinhQuangHiếu thats going to work great for > 5 million users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only user node(s) matching a specific user name, you need a query:

```
FIRDatabase
  .database().reference()
  .child("users")
  .queryOrdered(byChild: "credentials/username")
  .queryEqual(toValue: "MyUsername")
  .observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```

Also see the [Firebase documentation on ordering and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sort_data).